# 'Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.' error

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

Since I wanted to examine [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper) source code, I imported it into Android Studio. I got a few other errors before and fixed them. This is annoying, now I have a new error.
I am getting this error:

```
Build file 'C:\Users\hange\Desktop\libgdx-demo-superjumper-master\desktop\build.gradle' line: 18

A problem occurred evaluating project ':desktop'.
> Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

My "desktop\build.gradle" file looks like this. I specified line 18 there.

```
apply plugin: "java"

sourceCompatibility = 1.6
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]

project.ext.mainClassName = "com.badlogicgames.superjumper.desktop.DesktopLauncher"
project.ext.assetsDir = new File("../android/assets");

task run(dependsOn: classes, type: JavaExec) {
    main = project.mainClassName
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    standardInput = System.in
    workingDir = project.assetsDir
    ignoreExitValue = true
}

task dist(type: Jar) {
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.classesDir)   // THIS IS 18th LINE.
    from files(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    from {configurations.compile.collect {zipTree(it)}}
    from files(project.assetsDir);
 
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': project.mainClassName
    }
}

dist.dependsOn classes
```

EDIT: My "build.gradle" file looks like this. But I noticed that it can't resolve the json library. Probably the error is here because we are pulling the gradle version from a json file on the internet.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper // Cannot resolve symbol 'json'

buildscript {

    ant.get(src: 'https://libgdx.com/service/versions.json', dest: 'versions.json')
    def versionFile = file('versions.json')
    def json
    if (versionFile.exists()) {
        json = new JsonSlurper().parseText(versionFile.text)
    } else throw new GradleException("Unable to retrieve latest versions, please check your internet connection")

    ext {
        gdxVersion = json.libgdxRelease
        roboVMVersion = json.robovmVersion
        roboVMGradleVersion = json.robovmPluginVersion
        androidToolsVersion = json.androidBuildtoolsVersion
        androidSDKVersion = json.androidSDKVersion
        androidGradleToolsVersion = json.androidGradleToolVersion
        gwtVersion = json.gwtVersion
        gwtGradleVersion = json.gwtPluginVersion
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:$gwtGradleVersion"
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:$androidGradleToolsVersion"
        classpath "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:$roboVMGradleVersion"
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you building with the same version of Gradle as defined in the project (e.g. 4.6)? If not, and you are trying to upgrade it to a newer version, I recommend looking at the [migration guides](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_7.html) first.

Comment: @BjørnVester I'm using the same as that of the project. The android gradle plugin version of the project is $androidGradleToolsVersion.
I noticed that this is being read from a json file, in the build.gradle part and I edited my question (cannot resolve the json) can you take a look at the edit?

Comment: I am not talking about the Android plugin but rather the Gradle version. I still think you are running with a newer version of Gradle than what the project is designed for. The `classesDir` property was removed in Gradle 5.x (can't remember which minor version) and replaced with `classesDirs` (in plural). Try building on the command line with `gradlew build`, and then run `gradlew --version` to check the version. If you normally build in your IDE, maybe it is configured to ignore the wrapper script and use another Gradle distribution.

Comment: @BjørnVester I was using Gradle 6.5, I tried using 4.8.1 but got this error: Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 4.8.1. Do you have an idea? Does that mean the project is designed for version 6.5 of gradle?

Comment: The source code is more than three years old, so I doubt it is compatible with newer versions of Gradle. But somehow it seems to bring in the newest Android plugin. As it was designed for older versions, you either need to see if you can stop it from depending on the "latest and greatest", but rather the version that was present at the time - or upgrade everything, which is probably not an easy task if you are new to all this. I don't know much about Android myself, so I can't help unfortunately.

Comment: @BjørnVester yes with the data it pulls from json it brings in the newest Android plugin. Instead of reading from the json I manually gave a value and fixed the problem, thank you. I had to fix a few more error because the code was coded based on the json file, but I managed to run it. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting the solution in case anyone else has the same problem:
androidToolsVersion, androidSDKVersion, androidGradleToolsVersion, gwtGradleVersion

These 4 variables are pulled from a json file on the internet, but the value pulled from the json file may not always work correctly. Make the variables compatible.

For example this code is using classesDir.The classesDir property was removed in Gradle 5.x.
If you pull to Gradle 4.8.1, you will get the error "Minimum supported Gradle version is 6.5. Current version is 4.8.1.". To fix this error you have to assign 3.2.x value compatible with 4.8.1 gradle version to the androidGradleToolsVersion variable.

```
androidGradleToolsVersion = "3.2.1"
```